# angular4-carousel not showing

Tags: angular, carousel

I am attempting to get the [angular4-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-carousel) to work with my angular 4 app
It gives no errors but it does not display

I put this in my app.component.html

```
<carousel [sources]="imageSources" [config]="config"></carousel>
```

I put this in my app.component.ts

```
public imageSources: string[] = [
 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/',
 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/'
];

public config: ICarouselConfig = {
verifyBeforeLoad: true,
log: true,
animation: true,
animationType: AnimationConfig.SLIDE,
autoplay: true,
autoplayDelay: 2000,
stopAutoplayMinWidth: 768
};
```

The page loads but no carousel. Is there some specific css that I need to include?

Comment: please be more specified about ` angular4-carousel`(is there quick link to let others see the package). also make a runnable plunker to reproduce your problem will be better to let others quick know what you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the installation steps as given below

In app.module.ts

```
import { CarouselModule } from 'angular4-carousel';
```

add carousel in your module imports section

```
imports: [CarouselModule]
```

In component file;

```
import { ICarouselConfig, AnimationConfig } from 'angular4-carousel';
```

and the configuration is ok from your question.

In addition please check  that if you use CLI, import css file to angular-cli.json file in css section; if not, you have to add below code to index.html or import below css path to common style.css file

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: If you used system.js can you guide me I there are always error. Error loading http://localhost:5555/node_modules/angular4-carousel/src/app/services.js as "./src/app/services" from http://localhost:5555/node_modules/angular4-carousel/index.js